# Debugging Scala compiler code

Tags: scala, compiler-construction

I need to understand how Scala compiler works.

So I have cloned Scala git repository containing Scala compiler code
What should be my next steps to debug compiler part of the code base?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to [IDE setup](https://github.com/scala/scala#ide-setup) part of doc. And you will see there links to per-IDE instructions. E.g. [instructions](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/intellij/README.md) for IDEA are pretty useful. After all steps you just need to create `sandbox` dir in project root, create your `Test.scala` class in `sandbox`
And than run/debug